# Error: change the --out parameter error in R

Tags: c++, r, plink

I am trying to generate a file using Plink with your independently statistically significant hits. I have ran the command:

```
 system("plink/plink --bfile data/ BB5707 --clump results/results_1741182.assoc.log --clump-p1 5e-08 --clump-p2 0.05 --clump-r2 0.1 --clump-kb 250 --out results/results_1741182.assoc.linear_clumped.clumped")
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Failed to open results/results_1741182.assoc.linear_clumped.clumped.log.  Try changing the --out parameter.
[1] 2
```

What do you suggest is wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove ".clumped" from the end of your output name